# No stored procedure on SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with java and Microsoft SQL server. I want to run stored procedure from my app and it works just fine on my computer. But when the customer tries the same app there is an error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SaQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'schema.PROCEDURE_NAME'
```

So the first thing I tried was obviously printing the list of procedures. I used this code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dbConfig.getDbServerAddress() + ":" + dbConfig.getDbServerPort() + ";databaseName=" + dbConfig.getDbServerDatabase(),
                dbConfig.getDbServerUsername(), dbConfig.getDbServerPassword());

      DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
      ResultSet res = meta.getProcedures(null, null, null); 
      log.info("List of procedures: "); 
      while (res.next()) {
         log.info(
            "   "+res.getString("PROCEDURE_CAT") 
           + ", "+res.getString("PROCEDURE_SCHEM")
           + ", "+res.getString("PROCEDURE_NAME"));
      }
```

Again, on my computer it worked well and I got all procedures (system procedures and also that one I want from the specific schema). On customer side there is only list of sys procedures. The only thing I can see is that there is no such procedure in customer database or the user from DB connection does not have enough rights to run/see it. But I got response from customer that the procedure is really in DB and they can run it with same user from Delphi application.

Do you have any idea what can cause such a problem? Is there something to set in MS SQL server for running stored procedures from java app? I use java 1.8 and I have MS SQL server 2014 (customer has 2012 version but I guess it should be fine). I use sqljdbc4.jar for connection.

The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SP_KASYS_GETINFO]
@CisloPruvodky varchar(20),
@SAPKod varchar(20) output,
@NazevMaterialu varchar(50) output,
@Mnozstvi int output,
@BIN varchar(20) output,
@DatumVyroby datetime output
as select top 1 @SAPKod = MatCode, @NazevMaterialu = MatDescr, @Mnozstvi = Quantity, @BIN = BIN, @DatumVyroby = ProductionDate
from FLXT_BIN where LabelNumber = @CisloPruvodky and ImportState = 0
```

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: is the stored procedure in the same schema as it is on your local system? maybe the stored procedure on your customer side is in the default [dbo] schema and you're referring it from a particular schema.

Comment: Does the database user have permission to execute the procedure? Does that user have permission to the schema? As a side note, your query is using top but there is order by. This means you don't know which row will be returned.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're looking in the right database?

Comment: The user should be granted access to the DBO schema.

Comment: @Sushil : yes, the schema is same (dbo)

Comment: @SeanLange : database user can execute it because my co-worker tried that from Management Studio and it worked (same user as in app)

Comment: @AaronBertrand : yes, database is really the same

Comment: @XtremeBytes : well, I guess he is because he could not run the procedure from Management Studio otherwise, right?

Comment: the username that you're using for connecting to the database, does it have rights to access this stored procedure?

Comment: @Sushil : yes, it has rights.. same username is used in Delphi application which works fine and can run this stored procedure.

Comment: can you create this procedure as a string and execute it from your code? try and see if you get any errors. if the procedure does exist, it will throw u an error or it will get created.